# Regarding MPLS L2 Vs L3

Tags: layer2, layer3, mpls

I'm studying about MPLS Network, i've doubt on that i.e.,

what is the difference between MPLS Layer-2 Vs Layer-3 Network ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short answer:

A L2 VPN acts like a layer 2 network.  That is, all the devices that connect to the VPN would normally be on the same subnet, and broadcasts go to all devices.

In a L3 VPN, each site makes a L3 point to point link to the MPLS provider.  Each site must run a routing protocol (or use static routing) with the provider to reach other sites.

Another way to think about it is, a L2 VPN acts like a virtual switch, while a L3 VPN acts like a virtual router.

Answer (score 2):

- L2 VPN think of it as a big distributes Ethernet switch
- L3 VPN think of it as a big distributed router

Pseudowire or VLL (Virtual Local Loop) is a special variant of a L2 VPN which acts more like a L1 service (plain cable) as there is no mac learning inside the MPLS cloud and it can only be point to point where VPLS acts like a switch and dies mac learning and is point to multipoint.